# Codeigniter automatically add field to order_by

Tags: codeigniter

I want to get most view by query:

```
        $this->db->select("a.pid, a.title, a.pic, a.date_created, d.view as post_view");
        $this->db->from("posts as a");
        $this->db->join('views as d', 'd.post_id=a.pid');  
        $this->db->join('cats as b', 'b.catid=a.catid'); //ensure Cat existed
        $this->db->where("a.block", 0);
        $this->db->order_by("d.view", "desc");
        $this->db->limit(5);
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->result();
```

but always automatically add order_by **`pid` asc**. and **never** order desc for **d.view** field.  i try to print query string and here:

```
SELECT `a`.`pid`, `a`.`title`, `a`.`pic`, `a`.`date_created`, `d`.`view` as `post_view` FROM `posts` as `a` JOIN `views` as `d` ON `d`.`post_id`=`a`.`pid` JOIN `cats` as `b` ON `b`.`catid`=`a`.`catid` WHERE `a`.`block` =0 ORDER BY `pid` asc, `d`.`view` DESC LIMIT 5
```

Any suggestion to fix? (CI version 3.*)

Comment: it is showing correct query by my side? show how u doing

Comment: Hi Pradeep, 
I try simple query only views table (views table not pid field), and get error. 
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'desc ORDER BY `pid` asc' at line 3

SELECT * FROM `views` as `d` WHERE d.view desc ORDER BY `pid` asc

Comment: should be like this `SELECT * FROM views as d  ORDER BY d.view desc `

Comment: Yeap, i see; but i am using CI query syntax:
        $this->db->from("views as d");
        $this->db->where("d.view desc");
        $query = $this->db->get();
        $rs = $query->result();

Comment: where clause is wrong use this : `$this->db->select("*");
         $this->db->from("views as d"); 
         $this->db->order_by("d.view", "DESC");
         $query = $this->db->get(); 
         $rs = $query->result();`

Comment: I try with your code, but: 
Error Number: 1054

Unknown column 'pid' in 'order clause'

SELECT * FROM `views` as `d` ORDER BY `pid` asc, `d`.`view` DESC

Comment: this is strange ,do you have pid column in your views table?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173323/discussion-between-tuan-huynh-and-pradeep).